# I think I have a gem incompatibility when trying to install the devise_masquerade gem. How do I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try start my application on Docker, I get an error message:

> Could not find gem 'devise_masquerade (>-0) ruby' in any of the gem
>   sources listed in your Gemfile or available on this machine.

I don't understand what the issue is since I included the devise_masquerade gem to my Gemfile and it appears in my Gemfile lock. My client wants to keep rails 4.0.0 and so that's my only restriction when it comes to gem versions. What can I do to fix this problem? What is the problem? Is there a gem incompatibility?

This is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
# ruby '2.0.0'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
# gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', "~> 0.3.15"
gem 'pg', "~> 0.17.1"
gem "activerecord4-redshift-adapter", github: "aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter"

# Cache
gem 'dalli'

# AWS SDK
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 1.0'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
# gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

# Excel Generation
gem 'axlsx_rails'

# CORS
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'

# JWT
gem 'jwt', '~> 1.0'

#Importing Excel
gem 'roo'

gem 'request_store'

# for whitelabel
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :test, :development do

  # Development
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'better_errors'             # Output a much better error page
  gem 'binding_of_caller'         #  - REPL for better_errors
  gem 'meta_request'              # Supporting gem for Rails Panel (Chrome Extension)
  # gem 'rails-dev-tweaks', git: "git://github.com/yellowhammer/rails-dev-tweaks.git"
  gem 'rails-dev-boost', git: "git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git"

  # Testing 
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'faker'
  gem "shoulda-matchers", '2.5.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner' 
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'        # Use factories instead of fixtures
  gem 'json_expressions'          # Better testing for JSON patterns
  gem 'mocha_rails'               # Mocha Testing Framework / Chai
  gem 'ci_reporter', '1.9.1'      # needed for jenkins
  gem "codeclimate-test-reporter" # needed for jenkins integration with codeclimate
  gem 'simplecov'                 # needed to generate code coverage reports
  gem 'simplecov-rcov'            # needed to generate code coverage report that ruby metrics plugin understands
  gem 'spring-commands-rspec'     # integrate spring for rspec for faster testing

  gem 'pry'
  gem "pry-remote", :require => "pry-remote"
  gem 'slim'

  gem "bullet"
  gem "rubocop"
end

gem 'sinatra', require: false

# Devise (authentication)
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4'
gem 'devise_masquerade'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2', "0.2.2"

# Permissioning
gem 'authority', "~> 2.9.0"

# Versionist
gem 'versionist', "~> 1.2.1"

# JSON serialization
gem "active_model_serializers", "~> 0.8.1"

# For soft deletes
gem "soft_deletion", "~> 0.4.6"

# Application settings
gem "rails_config", "~> 0.3.3"

gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.2.0'

# Segment.io
gem 'analytics-ruby', '<1.0'

# Paper Trail for object auditing
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 3.0.5'

# RestClient + Nokogiri for fetching/parsing LiveRail API (until extracted to private gem)
gem 'rest-client', '~> 1.7'
gem 'nokogiri', '~> 1.6'

gem 'sidekiq', '~> 3.3'
gem 'puma',  '~>2.11'

# AppNexus Wrapper
source 'http://geminabox.rhinoserve.com:8080' do 
  gem 'appnexus', '0.0.7'
end
```

This is my gemlock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter.git
  revision: 72692fd7e08d67a1834f6ad3ff90cafa35d5df8f
  specs:
    activerecord4-redshift-adapter (0.1.1)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
      pg
​
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/thedarkone/rails-dev-boost.git
  revision: 15ebc37b3f1b424ce7f5a160d2a8f890023208e6
  specs:
    rails-dev-boost (0.3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
​
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://geminabox.rhinoserve.com:8080/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.0.13)
      actionpack (= 4.0.13)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.0.13)
      activesupport (= 4.0.13)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    active_model_serializers (0.8.3)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
    activemodel (4.0.13)
      activesupport (= 4.0.13)
      builder (~> 3.1.0)
    activerecord (4.0.13)
      activemodel (= 4.0.13)
      activerecord-deprecated_finders (~> 1.0.2)
      activesupport (= 4.0.13)
      arel (~> 4.0.0)
    activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.4)
    activesupport (4.0.13)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      minitest (~> 4.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.37)
    analytics-ruby (0.6.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8)
      faraday_middleware (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    appnexus (0.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      rest-client
    arel (4.0.2)
    ast (2.0.0)
    astrolabe (1.3.1)
      parser (~> 2.2)
    authority (2.9.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
    awesome_print (1.2.0)
    aws-sdk (1.64.0)
      aws-sdk-v1 (= 1.64.0)
    aws-sdk-v1 (1.64.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.4)
    axlsx (2.0.1)
      htmlentities (~> 4.3.1)
      nokogiri (>= 1.4.1)
      rubyzip (~> 1.0.0)
    axlsx_rails (0.3.0)
      axlsx (>= 2.0.1)
      rails (>= 3.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.10)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    builder (3.1.4)
    bullet (4.14.7)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      uniform_notifier (~> 1.9.0)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    celluloid (0.16.0)
      timers (~> 4.0.0)
    ci_reporter (1.9.1)
      builder (>= 2.1.2)
    codeclimate-test-reporter (0.4.7)
      simplecov (>= 0.7.1, < 1.0.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    connection_pool (2.2.0)
    dalli (2.7.4)
    database_cleaner (1.4.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    devise (3.4.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      responders
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    domain_name (0.5.23)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.5.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faker (1.4.3)
      i18n (~> 0.5)
    faraday (0.9.1)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday_middleware (0.9.1)
      faraday (>= 0.7.4, < 0.10)
    hashie (3.4.1)
    hike (1.2.3)
    hitimes (1.2.2)
    htmlentities (4.3.3)
    http-cookie (1.0.2)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    json (1.8.2)
    json_expressions (0.8.3)
    jwt (1.4.1)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    meta_request (0.3.4)
      callsite (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.11)
      rack-contrib (~> 1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0.0, < 5.0.0)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    mini_portile (0.6.2)
    minitest (4.7.5)
    mocha_rails (0.0.5)
      rails (>= 3.1.0)
    multi_json (1.11.0)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    mysql2 (0.3.18)
    netrc (0.10.3)
    nokogiri (1.6.6.2)
      mini_portile (~> 0.6.0)
    oauth2 (1.0.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (~> 1.2)
    omniauth (1.2.2)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.2)
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
      omniauth-oauth2
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.2.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paper_trail (3.0.7)
      activerecord (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
    parser (2.2.2.6)
      ast (>= 1.1, < 3.0)
    pg (0.17.1)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    pry (0.10.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.8.1)
      slop (~> 3.4)
    pry-remote (0.1.8)
      pry (~> 0.9)
      slop (~> 3.0)
    puma (2.11.2)
      rack (>= 1.1, < 2.0)
    quiet_assets (1.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-contrib (1.2.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-cors (0.3.1)
    rack-protection (1.5.3)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.0.13)
      actionmailer (= 4.0.13)
      actionpack (= 4.0.13)
      activerecord (= 4.0.13)
      activesupport (= 4.0.13)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.0.13)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    rails_config (0.3.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    railties (4.0.13)
      actionpack (= 4.0.13)
      activesupport (= 4.0.13)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.0.0)
    rake (10.4.2)
    rdoc (4.2.0)
      json (~> 1.4)
    redis (3.2.1)
    redis-namespace (1.5.2)
      redis (~> 3.0, >= 3.0.4)
    request_store (1.1.0)
    responders (1.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 4.2)
    rest-client (1.8.0)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3.0)
      netrc (~> 0.7)
    roo (1.13.2)
      nokogiri
      rubyzip
      spreadsheet (> 0.6.4)
    rspec-collection_matchers (1.1.2)
      rspec-expectations (>= 2.99.0.beta1)
    rspec-core (2.99.2)
    rspec-expectations (2.99.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.1.3, < 2.0)
    rspec-mocks (2.99.3)
    rspec-rails (2.99.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-collection_matchers
      rspec-core (~> 2.99.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 2.99.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 2.99.0)
    rubocop (0.32.1)
      astrolabe (~> 1.3)
      parser (>= 2.2.2.5, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.4)
    ruby-ole (1.2.11.8)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
    rubyzip (1.0.0)
    sass (3.2.19)
    sass-rails (4.0.5)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.2)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, < 3.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    shoulda-matchers (2.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    sidekiq (3.3.3)
      celluloid (>= 0.16.0)
      connection_pool (>= 2.1.1)
      json
      redis (>= 3.0.6)
      redis-namespace (>= 1.3.1)
    simplecov (0.9.2)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.9.0)
    simplecov-html (0.9.0)
    simplecov-rcov (0.2.3)
      simplecov (>= 0.4.1)
    sinatra (1.4.6)
      rack (~> 1.4)
      rack-protection (~> 1.4)
      tilt (>= 1.3, < 3)
    slim (3.0.3)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slop (3.6.0)
    soft_deletion (0.4.6)
    spreadsheet (1.0.3)
      ruby-ole (>= 1.0)
    spring (1.3.4)
    spring-commands-rspec (1.0.4)
      spring (>= 0.9.1)
    sprockets (2.12.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.4)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    temple (0.7.5)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    timers (4.0.1)
      hitimes
    tzinfo (0.3.43)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.6)
    uniform_notifier (1.9.0)
    versionist (1.2.1)
      rails (>= 3)
      yard (~> 0.7)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    yard (0.8.7.6)
​
PLATFORMS
  ruby
​
DEPENDENCIES
  active_model_serializers (~> 0.8.1)
  activerecord4-redshift-adapter!
  analytics-ruby (< 1.0)
  appnexus (= 0.0.7)!
  authority (~> 2.9.0)
  awesome_print (~> 1.2.0)
  aws-sdk (~> 1.0)
  axlsx_rails
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bullet
  ci_reporter (= 1.9.1)
  codeclimate-test-reporter
  dalli
  database_cleaner
  devise (~> 3.4)
  factory_girl_rails
  faker
  json_expressions
  jwt (~> 1.0)
  meta_request
  mocha_rails
  mysql2 (~> 0.3.15)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6)
  omniauth-google-oauth2 (= 0.2.2)
  paper_trail (~> 3.0.5)
  pg (~> 0.17.1)
  pry
  pry-remote
  puma (~> 2.11)
  quiet_assets
  rack-cors
  rails (~> 4.0.0)
  rails-dev-boost!
  rails_config (~> 0.3.3)
  request_store
  rest-client (~> 1.7)
  roo
  rspec-rails (~> 2.0)
  rubocop
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.0)
  sdoc
  shoulda-matchers (= 2.5.0)
  sidekiq (~> 3.3)
  simplecov
  simplecov-rcov
  sinatra
  slim
  soft_deletion (~> 0.4.6)
  spring-commands-rspec
  versionist (~> 1.2.1)
​
BUNDLED WITH
   1.10.6
```

Comment: Why is it commented out in your `Gemfile`? `# gem 'devise_masquerade'`

Comment: ah sorry, it was a typo

Comment: fix that and run `bundle install`, then try again.

Comment: Jwan622, were you able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'devise_masquerade'
```

Then run:

`bundle install`

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
gem install packet-name -v '1.0.0'
```

I get errors like this:

```
xill@atawho:/opt/metasploit-framework$ msfconsole 
**Could not find cucumber-1.3.19 in any of the sources**
```

So try:

```
gem install cucumber -v '1.3.19'
```